# Do I have to install "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" package when using User Secrets in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I see some blog posts are saying one should install the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets` package first to using User Secrets file in ASP.NET Core project.

For [this post](https://dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2023/03/02/how-to-set-up-user-secrets-for-net-core-projects-in-visual-studio/), [this one](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/using-user-secrets-configuration-in-net/), and [this one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/secure-development-in-net-an-introduction-to-usersecrets2), there are all saying we have to install this package.

[image]

I never install this package before and I can use User Secrets without any issue. I also checked `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` that doesn't included `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets` package either. So what's this package for? Do I have to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets` already exists as a dependency of something already referenced: another package or app framework you don't need another reference (in .NET 8 RC2 `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` includes `...UserSecrets`).

Comment: .NET RC2: Do you mean .NET 8? I was tested in .NET 7.

Comment: @WillHuang corrected. I don't have a .NET 7 Web App project to hand... however the .NET 6 web app project I have also has the framework including the `...UserSecrets` dependency.

Comment: I can only see this `<Using Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" />` from this file: `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\Sdk\Sdk.props`

Comment: @WillHuang look at the condition on the containing `<ItemGroup>`: that is for implicit usings.

Comment: That's the `namespace`, I mean the NuGet package.